# Matching a string where certain punctuation can exist inside or after the string in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if a word exists in a string with regex and JavaScript but I'm struggling to get it right.

The matched string can only have a space or nothing before it. The matched string can't have alphanumeric characters or punctuation directly behind it. The matched string can't have alphanumeric characters straight after it, only `!`, `,` , `.`, a space, or nothing. Examples are below!

Currently my regex looks like this:

`\w*(?<![^ ])\bHello\b`

If you test `Hello`, `Hello!`,  `Hello` or `Hello`  it returns true as expected.

If you test `.Hello`, `aHello` or `Helloa` it returns false as expected.

However I have two problems:

- It returns true if you pass it `Hello:`, `Hello?`, `Hello)` etc. which is not what I want, only `!`, `,` , `.` should be allowed.
- It does not work for strings with punctuation - I will need to check if the strings `D:`, `:D`, and `<3` exist in a sentence. I believe this is due to my use of `\b`

I tried converting `\b` into what it does under the hood and modifying that, but I couldn't get it to work how I wanted to so I have turned to StackOverflow. I'm OK with having a regex for alphanumeric strings and another one for strings with symbols like `:` and `<`. Or if you think it's best to just switch to manual checking with a JavaScript function then that's OK too.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a lookahead to restrict what's allowed after the string.

Comment: rather than having 2 different regex (might depend on ur use-case but), you can the OR operator whereever it can apply. As for your 2 problems: the 1st one where it returns true instead of pass is because you did not mention `$` ending. And it won't work with strings with punctuation bcos punctuation is not a string, so treat punctuation as literal characters separately (see answers below). And `\b` is to make ur search `whole word` (when used at both ends of a word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<!\S)Hello(?=[!,.\s]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XAByYv/1).

*Details*

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `Hello` - some word
- `(?=[!,.\s]|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `!`, `,`, `.`, whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any `lookarounds`, Here's my regex.

I had to put the regex in the `forEach` loop because of the `regex's lastIndex` property which continues matching from the index of the last match.

[`Test it out`](http://regexr.com/5qvrt)

```js
const regex = /^ ?Hello(?:!|,|\.| |$)/gm;
const trueCases = [" Hello", "Hello!", "Hello", " Hello "];
const falseCases = [".Hello","aHello","Helloa","Hello:","Hello?","Hello)"];

console.log(trueCases.map(trueCase => /^ ?Hello(?:!|,|\.| )?$/gm.test(trueCase)));
console.log(falseCases.map(falseCase => /^ ?Hello(?:!|,|\.| )?$/gm.test(falseCase)));
```

Answer (score 1):

another version:
`^[ ]?[\w:<]+[\!\*. ]?$`

explanation with examples are on link: https://regex101.com/r/UtGaHB/1

There are 3 parts to it

1. `^[ ]?`   : start (`^`) with either space or nothing (`?` means its optional)
2. `[\w:<]+` : all lengths (+) of alphanumeric `\w` or `:` or `<`
3. `[\!\*. ]?$` : end (`$`) with optional(`?`) literal characters `!`, `*`, `.` or `space`

Note that if you specifically want to search Hello (case-sensitive): you would need to change 2nd part